# Webpack Encore + Symfony - Use modules loaded from base

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack

I am miggrating an old big symfony web app to webpack encore. For now, I installed all js libraries, but I found a problem:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: xxx is not defined**

My structure is the next.

- common.js where I import js libraries that I was used in a lot of pages (like resize-sensor).
- base.html.twig where I call {{ encore_entry_script_tags('common') }}
- Final views which extends base.html.twig

In common.js I load librarys: Ej.
import 'resize-sensor';

In a view I try to use:
new ResizeSensor(jQuery('#div-left'), function(){fixElements();});

I got this error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ResizeSensor is not defined"

I had to import jquery, highcharts and confirmation2 globally, but I am not sure that i want to do this with all libraries.

So is there any way to import all content from common in all views which extends from base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a view I try to use: new ResizeSensor(jQuery('#div-left'), function(){fixElements();});

Importing libs in your js-files, doesn't make then "available" in global scope. So you can't just use them in your views like

```
{% block javascripts %}
   {{ parent() }}
   <script>
     $(function(){
        new ResizeSensor(jQuery('#div-left'), function(){fixElements();});
     });
   </script>
{% endblock %}
```

They are actually available only in that file (common.js)

You could try to use special `global.` syntax OR you try to make them as `autoProvidedVariables`. You have to play around which works best for you

`global`

```js
// in your common.js

import ResizeSensor from 'resize-sensor';

global.ResizeSensor = ResizeSensor; // now is ResizeSensor available globaly
```

`autoProvideVariables`

```js
// in webpack.config.js

.autoProvidejQuery()
.autoProvideVariables({
   ResizeSensor:  require.resolve('resize-sensor'),
}
```

**now** you could use them in your views.

Comment: Hi and thank's for your response.

The true is that I can call ResizeSensor importing as global, but It fail when I use autoprovideVariables ...

Comment: @AlbertoPosada yes, I was wrong about `autoProvideVariables()` It has different purpose (https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html#fixing-jquery-plugins-that-expect-jquery-to-be-global)